# SSH hangs/disconnects unless using `-v` option

Tags: ssh, wifi, raspberry-pi, performance, ethernet

I have a raspberry pi setup. When connected over ethernet ssh sometimes hangs, but generally works. When connected over wifi ssh is extremely choppy (8/10 connections fail, if I connect it drops within 5 minutes).

The interesting part: `ssh -v pi.local` works flawlessly every time. Potentially some sort of network issue, that the verboseness of `-v` fixes? Acting as a keep alive?

Any idea what config I can set to get this reliable connection without `-v`? Keep-alives? QOS settings? TCP fun?

This is a default Raspbian Bullseye install (Debian), with no system network config changes other than setting wifi SSID/password. Wifi signal is strong.

I have a Tailscale VNP setup, and the issues don't occur when using it for SSH. I'm guessing the extra layer of the wireguard tunnel resolves what ever routing or packet dropping is causing this. It's only when I try to access it over local network (not the VPN) that I have issues.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Offhand, my first guess would be your network configuration is screwed up. But you gave no details on that, so ... ?

Comment: I would do two network captures, one for ssh -v, one for ssh without -v and try and spot the differences. Even though, AFAIK, and excluding bugs, -v should have no influence on what is sent over the network other than possibly on timing.

Comment: Updated original question with details. Default fresh install so screwed up network config unlikely (unless Tailscale install changed it). VPN is not involved in the problematic case (clarified that as well). I'm guessing the -v is working as a pseudo keep alive and resolving something on my network.

Comment: If you switch off your tailscale VPN on the Pi can you then connect locally? If so it's a routing issue, probably to do with redirection of the LAN route to use the VPN

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
TCPKeepAlive yes
ServerAliveInterval 30
```

This would be applied to any ssh you make.

Comment: That didn't work for me. Connecting through my Tailscale network has fixed it (`ssh pi` instead of `ssh pi.local`), so not critical to find a fix. But leaving question up to help find issue.